# control reaches end of non-void function is error on xcode but not error on gcc

Tags: c++, xcode, gcc

hi i have a question.

```
bool testFunction(int arg) { int value = arg; }
```

this function is not error on gcc & vs. only warning occur.

but in xcode, this source is error.
"control reaches end of non-void function"

i dont know why error occur in xcode.

sure Treat Warnings as Errors option set NO in xcode.

thank you.

Comment: How about you just return a value?

Comment: haha. your comment is right. but, i did not write that source. Many people make similar mistakes, so I want an error. :)

Comment: Oh, I thought you were trying to eliminate the error message.  My bad.  CARRY ON!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, returning nothing from a `non-void` function is *Undefined Behavior*.

Remember that compilers are not supposed to eliminate UB from your code. They simply cannot detect all UB patterns; they can only warn about it when they "suspect it".

The fact that this pattern is left "allowed" is for backward compatibility with old code. It is the responsibility of the programmer.

In most, if not all compilers, there is an option to set this specific warning as an error. This option is other than the *"Treat all Warnings as Errors*". It seems to be set in your XCode environment. Look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18908129/xcode-5-what-was-a-warning-now-an-error-control-may-reach-end-of-non-void-func) for how to find this option in XCode.

Comment: thank you good information. above source exist in class in header file. and didn"t use it. but if i use that fuction, error is occur. i want erorr is occur in vs, even this function didn"t used.(because other people make same mistake.). is it possible???

Comment: not library, own my code. and vs version is 2012 :)

Comment: Which version of VS are you using? In my VS2015 it's an error.

Comment: VS2012 and 11.0.61219.00 update5. is it error occur that function only declare in headerfile without using the function?

Comment: If the function is *defined* in the header file then the error appears when compiling any in any source file that includes it.  BUT, if the function is only *declared* in the header file, then no, only where it is defined.

Answer (score 1):

Different compilers warn about different things.
An error or warning should really occur in this case because your function should return a value.

If you add the -Wall or -Wreturn-type flag to g++ you will get a warning.
You can do the equivalent in Xcode by adjusting the build setting 'Mismatched Return Type' value. There are three settings.

1. Yes - warning
2. No - ignore
3. Yes (error) - treat this as an error

See attached screenshot.

[image: Xcode option]

Turning this off might lead to you missing other errors so it would be best to leave it at the Warn setting at least.

Comment: @성정민 if the problem has been solved please select a correct answer. if not let us know if there are any other issues. this will also help because it will allow users to focus on open questions. thanks

Comment: Thank you! but, i think more important visual studio occur error than resolving ios error. because above source mistake source and bad situation. so, i need to occur error in vs. :)